# Flux and WebSockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, reactjs, flux

I'm using Flux and WebSocket in my Reactjs application and during implementation I've encountered some problems.

**Questions:**

- Assuming I have a set of a set of actioncreators and a store for managing the WebSocket connection, and that the connection is started in a actioncreator (`open(token)`), where should I put my `conn.emit`'s and how do I get other actions access to my connection object so that they can send data to the backend?
- Do I have to pass it as an argument to the actions that are called in the views (eg. `TodoActions.create(conn, todo)`) or is there a smarter way?

**[Current code is here](https://gist.github.com/jwadsager/efefd7916f809d4b8829)**

I'm using ES6 classes.

If I have omitted anything necessary in the gist, please let me know.

**EDIT:**

This is what I have concocted so far based on glortho's answer:

```
import { WS_URL } from "./constants/ws";
import WSActions from "./actions/ws";

class WSClient {
    constructor() {
        this.conn = null;
    }

    open(token) {
        this.conn = new WebSocket(WS_URL + "?access_token=" + token);
        this.conn.onopen = WSActions.onOpen;
        this.conn.onclose = WSActions.onClose;
        this.conn.onerror = WSActions.onError;

        this.conn.addEventListener("action", (payload) => {
            WSActions.onAction(payload);
        });

    }

    close() {
        this.conn.close();
    }

    send(msg) {
        return this.conn.send(msg);
    }
}

export default new WSClient();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a singleton module (not a store or an action creator) that handles opening the socket and directing traffic through. Then any action creator that needs to send/receive data via the socket just requires the module and makes use of its generic methods.

Here's a quick and dirty untested example (assuming you're using CommonJS):

SocketUtils.js:

```
var SocketActions = require('../actions/SocketActions.js');

var socket = new WebSocket(...);

// your stores will be listening for these dispatches
socket.onmessage = SocketActions.onMessage;
socket.onerror   = SocketActions.onError;

module.exports = {
  send: function(msg) {
    return socket.send(msg);
  }
};
```

MyActionCreator.js

```
var SocketUtils = require('../lib/SocketUtils.js');

var MyActionCreator = {
  onSendStuff: function(msg) {
    SocketUtils.send(msg);
    // maybe dispatch something here, though the incoming data dispatch will come via SocketActions.onMessage
  }
};
```

Of course, in reality you'll be doing better and different things, but this gives you a sense of how you might structure it.

Comment: Can you show how/outline how I can create such a singleton?

Comment: If I use ES6 classes, should I put the the `socket = new WebSocket...` in the constructor?

Comment: Sure, and then just export the instantiated class.

Comment: I've updated my question with my code so far, if it could be of use to others and to receive feedback if I've done something wrong.

Comment: Yeah looks good in theory! If it doesn't work let me know and I'll help.